# Django quiz application, REST, how to design models?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, tastypie

I am building django quiz application, and all data (questions/answers) should be available via REST service. 
I'll use tastypie for this.

I have in mind perfect result JSON, which may look like (single question with answers):

```
{
    "level": 1,
    "question": "Example question",
    "choices":[
        {
            "content":"Example answer 1",
            "valid": true
        },
        {
            "content":"Example answer 2",
            "valid": false
        },
        {
            "content":"Example answer 3",
            "valid": false
        },
        {
            "content":"Example answer 4",
            "valid": false
        }
    ]
},
```

Single question will ALWAYS contain exactly 4 answers, where one or more will be valid.

I am not sure how should I design django models for such pattern.

Should I create "Answer" model with question foreign key? Maybe other solution will work better in this case?
If so, how can I use django admin/web form to easly add new questions?

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: are you allowing them to select multiple answers which are valid.  you mentioned more than one valid answer per question.

Comment: Thats correct, each question (as above) will contain 4 answers, where one or more is valid. What is unclear?

Answer (score 3):

A model structure I've used in the past is as follows:

```
class Questionnaire(models.Model):
    version = models.CharField()

class Question(models.Model):
    questionnaire = models.ForeignKey(Questionnaire)
    text = models.CharField()

class QuestionAnswer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    text = models.CharField()
    is_valid = models.BooleanField()

class UserAnswer(models.Model):
    answer = models.ForeignKey(QuestionAnswer)
```

This solution would allow you to design multiple Questionnaires/Quizzes, each of which would have a variable number of questions. Then each question would have a variable number of answers and you can select the number of which are valid.

The biggest problem with this design is that it isn't really conducive to partial questionnaire/quiz completions. If that's a dealbreaker, you could adjust the UserAnswer class as follows:

```
class UserQuestionnaire(models.Model):
    questionnaire = models.ForeignKey(Questionnaire)
    completed = models.BooleanField()

class UserAnswer(models.Model):
    answer = models.ForeignKey(QuestionAnswer)
    user_questionnaire = models.ForeignKey(UserQuestionnaire)
```

This breaks normalization a little bit, but would allow you to have a set flag for whether the taker is finished or not.

Hopefully this helps you get started!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this very good tutorial on Medium.
https://medium.com/@nsjcorps/create-a-quiz-application-with-django-rest-framework-react-redux-part-one-f0fcae5103fd but generally it should look like this.

And I made this playlist on YouTube too: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I4LEMajjdjA&list=PLOOcfkIFw3os58bzJjtUfcmRae_Ht_dFw

````
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Quiz(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
   questions_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
   description = models.CharField(max_length=70)
   created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True,blank=True)
   slug = models.SlugField()
   roll_out = models.BooleanField(default=False)

   class Meta:
       ordering = [‘created’,]
       verbose_name_plural =”Quizzes”

   def __str__(self):
       return self.name


class Question(models.Model):
   quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   label = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
   order = models.IntegerField(default=0)

   def __str__(self):
      return self.label

class Answer(models.Model):
   question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   text = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
   is_correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.text


class QuizTakers(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   correct_answers = models.IntegerField(default=0)
   completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

   def __str__(self):
      return self.user.username


class Response(models.Model):
    quiztaker = models.ForeignKey(QuizTakers, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question.label


@receiver(post_save, sender=Quiz)
def set_default_quiz(sender, instance, created,**kwargs):
   quiz = Quiz.objects.filter(id = instance.id)



 quiz.update(questions_count=instance.question_set.filter(quiz=instance.pk).count())
@receiver(post_save, sender=Question)
def set_default(sender, instance, created,**kwargs):
 quiz = Quiz.objects.filter(id = instance.quiz.id)
 quiz.update(questions_count=instance.quiz.question_set.filter(quiz=instance.quiz.pk).count())
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Quiz)
def slugify_title(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
 instance.slug = slugify(instance.name)```
````